# Checkboxes with array model in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, model

Here are my checkboxes :

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.lang[0]" id="FR" ng-true-value="'FR'" ng-false-value="''"  checked/>FR
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.lang[1]" id="NL" ng-true-value="'NL'" ng-false-value="''" />NL
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.lang[2]" id="EN" ng-true-value="'EN'" ng-false-value="''" />EN
```

I'd like to check a language and update my model 'data.lang'

But i have a problem :

```
If second checkbox is checked i have :
   [null,"NL"]
If the third is checked i have :
   [null,null,'EN']
```

What i need to have :

```
If second checkbox is checked :
    ['NL']
If second and third are checked :
    ['NL','EN']
If all are checked :
    ['FR','NL','EN']
```

I don't know how to update my model like i want could you help me? Thanks

Comment: Invoke a function everytime  theres a change in these checkbox. Clue : Use `push` and `splice` on the `Array`

Comment: I tried with a function in ng-change but because i use data.lang[n] as model it bind on the nth position in the array

Comment: Make data.lang an array of objects with { val: 'en', checked: boolean } and change your inputs to one with an ng-repeat...

Comment: Please create a fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your data structure and ng-repeat your input similar to the below.

```
$scope.langs = [
  {
    val: 'en',
    checked: false
  }
]

<input type="checkbox" ng-repeat="lang in langs" ng-model="lang.checked">{{lang.val}}</input>
```

Then do something like:

```
$scope.sendMyData() {
  $scope.langs.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item.checked) $scope.myData.push(item.value);
  });
}
```

Comment: i need $scope.langs is equal to ['FR','NL','EN'] if all checbkoxes are checked, not [{val:'FR', checked: 'true'},{val:'NL', checked: 'true'},{val:'EN', checked: 'true'}]''

Comment: Before you ship that data off to wherever it is going to go, make an array from the checked fields of each object. Your current data model is going to cause you more harm than good.

Comment: See my edit for the function to handle conversion to your data structure.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `data.lang[]` has length 3. i.e. if one value will there then other will be `null`.

Try this with `ng-repeat` so it will work.

Comment: That's what I said in my answer above.